# Is it possible to have a project / a workspace that includes a extension in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

is it possible to have a project / a workspace in vscode that includes a extension?
I want to have a language extension as part of my project workspace so I need only one repository to sync.

I know there is something like a recommended extension settings, but it's not a public available extension.
I'm working on a project for which I have created a custom language extension for my own script language. I don't want to make a public release for the language as I only use it for my private projects.
VS Code seems to install the extensions in the folder %userprofile%.vscode\extensions\

Is it possible to pull the extension into the project / workspace without relaying on files in the default extensions folder?

Comment: just copy the extension dev folder to the VSC extension folder and restart VSC, no need to publish, or build a vsix file and use the top menu in the extensions bar: **Install from vsix**

Comment: You mean in the folder I mentioned in the original post? That's where it currently is. But if I move to another machine and clone the git repository of my project workspace it's not included.
Or is there an extensions folder within the workspace? I'm not aware of that.

Comment: just copy it over to your other computer, how many computer do you use, and how often do you update the extension, the other solution is to put in the marketplace

Comment: Thanks for the tip...
I want to learn for future projects and see if I can do something like that for my work job. I want to automate as much as possible and make on-boarding as easy and as fast as possible.